# Controlling Internet Explorer's "Play animations in web pages" option

Tags: html, internet-explorer, animated-gif

Is there a `<meta>` tag, HTTP header, JavaScript mechanism, etc. that allows my web app to enable the *Play animations in web pages* option in Internet Explorer's Advanced options section? Or, is there at least some way to detect whether this option is enabled?

My web app uses animated GIF images to show loading progress for AJAX requests and other long-running operations. If these animations are disabled, the app feels frozen or sluggish.

Answer (score 0):

There is no straightforward method of detecting these things using javascript or meta tag, at least none that I know of. However, it might be better to approach the situation on the basis of why you would want to. What is it that you can or cannot do in your script if these things are enabled/disabled? There is almost always a way to get around limitations, or at the very least, you can post a notice that your page works better with such and such turned on or off.